# Finding substring within occurrence of a special character

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a string with example

```
• How are you. • I am fine. • ThirdLine.
```

Now I want to detect all • occurrences and store in an array. The array would contain three entries

```
•How are you
•I am fine
•ThirdLine
```

How can this be done in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "• How are you. • I am fine. • ThirdLine.";
String[] list = str.split("\\•");
```

Comment: what is the meaning of \\ ?

Comment: please see here that what is \\ mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Split**()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with desired delimiter

```
 String[] splitted= line.split("\\•");  //line is your whole string
```