# JLine: File Completion doesn't work on Windows

Tags: java, jline

I want to use JLine to build a simple CLI. But I ran into a problem. File name completer doesn't work properly on Windows.

When I enter `8> first C:\` and press tab, completer do nothing although it should display all subfolders.

Here is my code:

```
ArgumentCompleter completer1 = new ArgumentCompleter(
    new StringsCompleter("first"),
    new FileNameCompleter(),
    new NullCompleter()
);

ArgumentCompleter completer2 = new ArgumentCompleter(
    new StringsCompleter("second"),
    new NullCompleter()
);

AggregateCompleter completer3 = new AggregateCompleter(
    completer1, completer2
);

ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader();
console.addCompleter(completer3);

while (true) {
    String line = console.readLine("8> ");
    if (line.isEmpty()){
        console.println();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, i am running from eclipse.. i just get prompt but cannot read my input.

Comment: You should use double backslash "\\".

Comment: Can you tell why in eclipse i can read input?When i run in eclipse i cant see any input being read from keyboard. I searched for eclipse console settings but nothing fancy found

Comment: See this question with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character