# Regular Expression for a valid year in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regex:

```
^\d{4}$
```

I want to use it as a pattern in Java, for example:

```
"add year ^\d{4}$"
```

But I get an error because it contains a backslash. How can I ignore that?

Comment: So what is the error you're getting?  The text of the error will generally suggest how to solve it.

Comment: See [What is the backslash character (\\\)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character)

Comment: i get an error that the year string does not match the pattern when i use ^\\d{4}$

Answer (score 1):

In Java strings, you have to escape the backslash:

```
"add year ^\\d{4}$"
```

Comment: when i do it this way the year string does not match it

Comment: The `^` matches the start of the input, so to have it in the middle of the string is probably what causes it not to match. You can try `"add year \\d{4}"`.

Answer (score 1):

As jqno stated, you need to escape the backslash. But there is another problem in your regex. `^` means beginning of the string. So, you are actually looking for `add year [beginning of the string]\d{4}[end of the string]`.

Use this instead:

```
"add year \\d{4}$"
```