# How do i check if string contains char sequence and backslash "\"?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get `true` in the following test. I have a string with the backslash, that for some reason doesn't recognized.

```
String s = "Good news\\ everyone!";
Boolean test = s.matches("(.*)news\\.");
System.out.println(test);
```

I've tried a lot of variants, but only one `(.*)news(.*)` works. But that actually means any characters after `news`, i need only with `\`.

How can i do that?

Comment: With `"\\."`, you are trying to match a `.` symbol, not a ``\``. Use `s.matches(".*news\\\\.*")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the backslash character (\\‌)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character)

Answer (score 2):

Group the elements at the end:`(.*)news\\(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead :

```
Boolean test = s.matches("(.*)news\\\\(.*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Boolean test = s.matches(".*news\\\\.*");
```

Here .* means any number of characters followed by news, followed by double back slashes (escaped in a string) and then any number of characters after that (can be zero as well).

With your regex what it means is:

- .* Any number of characters
- news\\ - matches by "news\" (see one slash)
- . followed by one character.

which doesn't satisfies for String in your program "Good news\ everyone!"

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for an escaped occurrence of a literal dot: `"."`.

Refactor your pattern as follows (inferring the last part as you need it for a full match):

```
String s = "Good news\\ everyone!";
System.out.println(s.matches("(.*)news\\\\.*"));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

**Explanation**

- The back-slash is used to escape characters and the back-slash itself in Java `String`s
- In Java `Pattern` representations, you need to double-escape your back-slashes for representing a literal back-slash (`"\\\\"`), as double-back-slashes are already used to represent special constructs (e.g. `\\p{Punct}`), or escape them (e.g. the literal dot `\\.`).
- `String.matches` will attempt to match the **whole** `String` against your pattern, so you need the terminal part of the pattern I've added

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
String s = "Good news\\ everyone!";
Boolean test = s.matches("(.*)news\\\\(.*)");
System.out.println(test);
```