# How to stop java replaceAll() from removing backslash?

Tags: java, string

I am writing some simple java code that looks in a string to find a value called `REPLACEALL`. Once it finds that string I have it replace it with a path name as a value (ex:`D:\test\path\something`). However, when I run the code it replace it fine but it removes the single  `\`. I am not sure why and have set up  a debug to see where it is happening. The original string gets passed in fine, its only when the string goes through the `replaceAll()` that it causes this issue.

**Java:**

```
String path = "D:\test\path\something";
String s1="select * from Webserver WHERE data= REPLCAEME";  
String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("REPLACEME"," ' " + path + " ' ");  
System.out.println(replaceString);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the backslash character (\\‌)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character)

Comment: Have you tried escaping your backslashes with `\\`?

Comment: @BillyBrown I can't modify the string, its preset by an api and  passed straight into the application to get replaced. So that's why I am having a hard time solving the issue

Comment: It seems you want to build up an SQL statement. In this case, this is anyhow the wrong approach. Have a look to `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @lugiorgi Somewhat, but as I mentioned just a few minute ago in the comments, I can't access the string contents, it is passed from an API and I pass it straight through to the replaceAll() method.  Unless....is there a way to add an extra backslash to the string before I pass it?

Comment: @Henry Not sure if I follow, I already have the SQL statement that only has half of the query done. So when the user selects an option in the front-end it replaces the placeholder in the SQL query with the  proper value.

Comment: @kane_004 and this is exactly the use case PreparedStatements are intended to solve. They also take care of SQL injection problems.

Comment: What if we're not fetching data via an api? We won't be able to use PreparedStatements then?

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is used as an escape character in strings, which means that you have to escape it itself as `\\`. Otherwise, it denotes special characters, e.g., `\t` denotes a tab space, so in your example `\test` effectively means `<tab>est`.