# Error while using Java Pattern compile with regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-greedy, java-12

I am trying to come up with correct regex for the below usecase:

prefix.string1.anyNumber.string2.anyNumber.string3

**example 1:** prefix.abcd.22.pqr.55.xyz

**example 2:** prefix.abcd.22.xyz

**example 3:** prefix.pqr.55.xyz

Need to generate a regex that I can use to generate Pattern in java.

I tried the below:

```
String regex = "prefix\.abcd\.\d\.pqr\.\d\.xyz|prefix\.abcd\.\d\.xyz|prefix\.pqr\.\d\.xyz"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

It does not work. I have not used patterns much before. Trying to figure out what I am missing here. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: are you using the matcher class to check if the string input matches with the regex

Comment: Do you need to match alternating string and numbers delimited by ".". Or just the given examples?

Comment: just the given examples

Comment: can you check this regex- prefix\.abcd\.F?[0-9]..pqr\..F?[0-9].xyz

Comment: Use this site to manipulate your regex - https://www.regextester.com/110436

Comment: as your numbers contain several digits you should use "\d+" for them.
and do not forget to escape \ in Java strings:
`String regex = "prefix\\.abcd\\.\\d+\\.pqr\\.\\d+\\.xyz|prefix\\.abcd\\.\\d+\\.xyz|prefix\\.pqr\\.\\d+\\.xyz";`

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/HFU1hw/1) help?

Comment: Try `prefix(?:(?:\.abcd\.22)?(?:\.pqr\.55)?|(?:\.abcd\.22))\.xyz` https://regex101.com/r/D0hOcr/1 In Java `String regex = "prefix(?:(?:\\.abcd\\.22)?(?:\\.pqr\\.55)?|(?:\\.abcd\\.22))\\.xyz";`

Comment: `String regex = "prefix\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.\\d+\\.[a-zA-Z]+(\\.\\d+\\.[a-zA-Z]+)?"`. This matches both `prefix.string.anyNumber.string` and `prefix.string.anyNumber.string.anyNumber.string`.

Comment: To make your pattern work, you have to use `\d+` and in Java double escape the backslashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the backslash character (\\\)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character)

Comment: String regex = "prefix\\.abcd\\.\\d+\\.pqr\\.\\d+\\.xyz|prefix\\.abcd\\.\\d+\\.xyz|prefix\\.pqr\\.\\d+\\.xyz"; works. I didnt realize I was quite close to the answer. Escaping \  and using \d+ helped. Can one of you post your comment as answer so that I can accept it? thanks